# component not re-rendering when underlying model changes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model data that is in hierarchical order. I am using a component to render the model data and another component to add data to the model. I am facing a problem where when I add a model data in root level, it renders correctly but when I try to add model data one level deep, the view doesn't get updated.

Here is a simple example that demonstrates my problem: http://jsbin.com/UhIdoxOR/1/

So if I add a question after root level question, the view gets updated. But if I try to add a question in child level then the view does not get updated. 
What can I do to make the appropriate component re-render when the model changes?

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `QuestionController` you have the `hasChildren` and `childQuestions` computed properties with `property('questions')`, but this is incorrect because `hasChildren` depends of `childQuestions.length` and `childQuestion` of `questions.@each.parentQuestionId` because of the filter. So you need to update to the following:

```
    App.QuestionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        needs: 'questions',
        questions: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.questions"),

        hasChildren: function () {
            return (this.get('childQuestions.length') > 0);
        }.property('childQuestions.length'),

        childQuestions: function () {
            return (this.get('questions').filterBy('parentQuestionId', parseInt(this.get('id'))));
        }.property('questions.@each.parentQuestionId')
    });
```

Here is your updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/UhIdoxOR/3/edit

Comment: Oh shoot, why didn't I see that. Thank you so very much Marcio.